# FPDF Cell Inside Line Break In PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

In FPDF there is any way to add InSite `$pdf->Cell()` Line Break In FPDF PHP. I am also trying MultiCell but formating and image creating a too much problems **can I trick and add "/n" new line in cell with wrap-up functionality**

[PDF Should Be Look Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVAm9.png)

[How Actually Fpdf Generate PDF Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVDvw.png)

How can I match both

```
$pdf->Ln();

$current_x = $start_x;
$current_y += 0;

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
foreach ($result as $row) {

    $pdf->SetX(15);

 
    $pdf->Cell(20, 24, $row["id"], 'TB', '', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(54, 24, 'Item'."\n".'RestOf', 'TB', '', '');
    $pdf->Cell(30, 24, $pdf->Image($image3, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 25), 'TB', '', 'C', false);

    $pdf->Cell(25, 24, 'QTY', 'TB', 0, '');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 24, 'PRICE ', 'TB', 0, '');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 24, 'TOTAL', 'TB', 0, '');

    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: `MultiCell()` is specifically there to allow printing text with line breaks. Use it. Otherwise this question will turn into an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: And don't call `Image()` inside `Cell()`. It makes no sense because `Image()` returns nothing.